# How do I detect which video source is playing with html5 video

Tags: html, html5-video, dom-events

I'm setting up analytics on our html5 videos. Since Chrome, Firefox, etc. currently play different file types (but may change in the future), is there a way with Javascript to get the video source that's actually being played by the browser?

Markup:

```
<video class="myclass">
    <source src="myvid.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" />
    <source src="myvid.webm" type="video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis" />
    <source src="myvid.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not exemplary coding style, but this works for me and should be enough to get you started:

```
<video class="myclass" onloadeddata="document.getElementById('source').innerHTML
                                        = 'Playing file ' + this.currentSrc">
    <source src="myvid.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" />
    <source src="myvid.webm" type="video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis" />
    <source src="myvid.ogv" type="video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis" />
</video>
<div id="source"></div>
```

Basically, you want the `currentSrc` property after the metadata has been loaded.

Comment: Wonderful, you got me going in the right direction.

My final code with some jQuery love looks like:

    $('.myclass').bind('loadeddata', function() {
        var playing_source = this.currentSrc;
        alert(playing_source);
    });

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I know this ticket is closed but I add another more official solution :
Just do like this:

```
$(".myclass")[0].currentSrc
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currentsrc.asp